# ModelBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ApplyAllConfigurations'?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, ef-fluent-api, ef-model-builder

I am following [this youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lwCVE_XgqI&t=1396s) video and at time [34:05](https://youtu.be/_lwCVE_XgqI?t=2048), It is architecure for ASP.Net core using EntityFramework Core and they are showing an extension method

```
    modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurations();
```

I tried this in my code and it throws error: 
*'ModelBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ApplyAllConfigurations' and no accessible extension method 'ApplyAllConfigurations' accepting a first argument of type 'ModelBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?*

Am I missing any reference? If not, How can I implement this in my Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your `ApplyAllConfigurations` method as follows. I am using this and its working perfectly.

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyAllConfigurations(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces()
            .Any(gi => gi.IsGenericType && gi.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityTypeConfiguration<>))).ToList();

        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(configurationInstance);
        }
    }

}
```

Note: Ensure that this extension method and your `DbContext` are in the same Assembly. Other wise specify the assembly name explicitly in the extension method.